# Postgresql no response when log says its ready to accept connections

Tags: postgresql, docker

I have a dockerized apps which uses a docker-compose file. In my `entrypoint.sh` I need to check whether postgres is already ready to accept connections.

```
while ! pg_isready  -h $DB_HOST -p 5432 -U $DB_USER
do
  echo "$(date) - waiting for database to start"
  sleep 2
done
```

On my docker-compose up, I cannot continue with running the whole application since it's stuck. Upon checking my logs, postgres says its ready to accept connections.

Here's the full logs:

```
Recreating tabi_database_1 ... 
Recreating tabi_database_1 ... done
Recreating tabi_web_1      ... done
Recreating tabi_client_1   ... done
Attaching to tabi_database_1, tabi_web_1, tabi_client_1
client_1    | /docker-entrypoint.sh: /docker-entrypoint.d/ is not empty, will attempt to perform configuration
client_1    | /docker-entrypoint.sh: Looking for shell scripts in /docker-entrypoint.d/
client_1    | /docker-entrypoint.sh: Launching /docker-entrypoint.d/10-listen-on-ipv6-by-default.sh
database_1  | 
database_1  | PostgreSQL Database directory appears to contain a database; Skipping initialization
database_1  | 
database_1  | 2021-06-16 15:40:38.341 UTC [1] LOG:  starting PostgreSQL 13.3 (Debian 13.3-1.pgdg100+1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian 8.3.0-6) 8.3.0, 64-bit
client_1    | 10-listen-on-ipv6-by-default.sh: info: Getting the checksum of /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
web_1       | pg_isready -U postgres
client_1    | 10-listen-on-ipv6-by-default.sh: info: /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf differs from the packaged version
web_1       | localhost:5432 - no response
client_1    | /docker-entrypoint.sh: Launching /docker-entrypoint.d/20-envsubst-on-templates.sh
web_1       | Wed Jun 16 15:40:38 UTC 2021 - waiting for database to start
database_1  | 2021-06-16 15:40:38.341 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "0.0.0.0", port 5432
database_1  | 2021-06-16 15:40:38.341 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv6 address "::", port 5432
client_1    | /docker-entrypoint.sh: Launching /docker-entrypoint.d/30-tune-worker-processes.sh
database_1  | 2021-06-16 15:40:38.348 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
client_1    | /docker-entrypoint.sh: Configuration complete; ready for start up
database_1  | 2021-06-16 15:40:38.353 UTC [26] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2021-06-16 15:40:17 UTC
database_1  | 2021-06-16 15:40:38.357 UTC [1] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
client_1    | 2021/06/16 15:40:38 [notice] 1#1: using the "epoll" event method
client_1    | 2021/06/16 15:40:38 [notice] 1#1: nginx/1.21.0
client_1    | 2021/06/16 15:40:38 [notice] 1#1: built by gcc 10.2.1 20201203 (Alpine 10.2.1_pre1) 
client_1    | 2021/06/16 15:40:38 [notice] 1#1: OS: Linux 5.4.72-microsoft-standard-WSL2
client_1    | 2021/06/16 15:40:38 [notice] 1#1: getrlimit(RLIMIT_NOFILE): 1048576:1048576
client_1    | 2021/06/16 15:40:38 [notice] 1#1: start worker processes
client_1    | 2021/06/16 15:40:38 [notice] 1#1: start worker process 32
client_1    | 2021/06/16 15:40:38 [notice] 1#1: start worker process 33
client_1    | 2021/06/16 15:40:38 [notice] 1#1: start worker process 34
client_1    | 2021/06/16 15:40:38 [notice] 1#1: start worker process 35
client_1    | 2021/06/16 15:40:38 [notice] 1#1: start worker process 36
client_1    | 2021/06/16 15:40:38 [notice] 1#1: start worker process 37
client_1    | 2021/06/16 15:40:38 [notice] 1#1: start worker process 38
client_1    | 2021/06/16 15:40:38 [notice] 1#1: start worker process 39
client_1    | 2021/06/16 15:40:38 [notice] 1#1: start worker process 40
client_1    | 2021/06/16 15:40:38 [notice] 1#1: start worker process 41
client_1    | 2021/06/16 15:40:38 [notice] 1#1: start worker process 42
client_1    | 2021/06/16 15:40:38 [notice] 1#1: start worker process 43
web_1       | localhost:5432 - no response
web_1       | Wed Jun 16 15:40:40 UTC 2021 - waiting for database to start
web_1       | localhost:5432 - no response
web_1       | Wed Jun 16 15:40:42 UTC 2021 - waiting for database to start
web_1       | localhost:5432 - no response
web_1       | Wed Jun 16 15:40:44 UTC 2021 - waiting for database to start
web_1       | localhost:5432 - no response
web_1       | Wed Jun 16 15:40:46 UTC 2021 - waiting for database to start
web_1       | localhost:5432 - no response
web_1       | Wed Jun 16 15:40:48 UTC 2021 - waiting for database to start
web_1       | localhost:5432 - no response
web_1       | Wed Jun 16 15:40:50 UTC 2021 - waiting for database to start
web_1       | localhost:5432 - no response
web_1       | Wed Jun 16 15:40:52 UTC 2021 - waiting for database to start
web_1       | localhost:5432 - no response
web_1       | Wed Jun 16 15:40:54 UTC 2021 - waiting for database to start
web_1       | localhost:5432 - no response
web_1       | Wed Jun 16 15:40:56 UTC 2021 - waiting for database to start
web_1       | localhost:5432 - no response
web_1       | Wed Jun 16 15:40:58 UTC 2021 - waiting for database to start
web_1       | localhost:5432 - no response
web_1       | Wed Jun 16 15:41:00 UTC 2021 - waiting for database to start
web_1       | localhost:5432 - no response
web_1       | Wed Jun 16 15:41:02 UTC 2021 - waiting for database to start
web_1       | localhost:5432 - no response
web_1       | Wed Jun 16 15:41:04 UTC 2021 - waiting for database to start
web_1       | localhost:5432 - no response
web_1       | Wed Jun 16 15:41:06 UTC 2021 - waiting for database to start
web_1       | localhost:5432 - no response
web_1       | Wed Jun 16 15:41:08 UTC 2021 - waiting for database to start
web_1       | localhost:5432 - no response
web_1       | Wed Jun 16 15:41:10 UTC 2021 - waiting for database to start
web_1       | localhost:5432 - no response
web_1       | Wed Jun 16 15:41:12 UTC 2021 - waiting for database to start
web_1       | localhost:5432 - no response
web_1       | Wed Jun 16 15:41:14 UTC 2021 - waiting for database to start
```

My docker-compose

```
version: "3"

services:
  database:
    image: postgres
    restart: always
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: ${DB_USER}
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: ${DB_PASSWORD}
      POSTGRES_DB: tabi_prod
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
  web:
    build: .
    restart: always
    ports:
      - ${APP_PORT}:${APP_PORT}
    environment:
      APP_PORT: ${APP_PORT}
      DB_USER: ${DB_USER}
      DB_PASSWORD: ${DB_PASSWORD}
      DB_HOST: ${DB_HOST}
      SECRET_KEY_BASE: ${SECRET_KEY_BASE}
    depends_on:
      - database

  client:
    build: ./app
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    depends_on:
      - web

volumes:
  postgres_data:
```

Answer (score 0):

The URL of your database isn't `localhost:5432` when you run it using docker-compose. Docker-compose creates a private network where each container has a name that matches the name in your docker-compose.yaml file.

Since you have the database hostname in your `DB_HOST` environment variable, you should set that to `database`.
Actually, with your docker-compose file the host name will always be `database`, so there's no need to have it in a variable. You can just hard-code it and change `DB_HOST: ${DB_HOST}` to `DB_HOST: database` in your docker-compose file.